# Should questions that require some research that comes after expertise in the subject be allowed on not?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

If **A** asks a question that require some research that comes after expertise in the subject and all. If **B** worked upon that, it can save time for **A** if he answers that question. Should this question be closed?

Example: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178946/list-of-special-characters-with-special-meaning-in-mongodb) asks for the *list special characters with special meaning in mongoDB*.

Should Newbie be allowed to ask this question?

Comment: The question you link to doesn't look like it requires *any* expertise in the subject to answer - your comment alludes to this fact.

Comment: @WaiHaLee may be the example given by me is not that good. But you must have got the intent of my question I guess.

Comment: There's an awkward conflict I have with a question like this where one side of me says, *"Hey, any answer to this question is probably going to be pretty great for the site's posterity, better than that troubleshooting question next to it with an MCVE."* The other conflicting side thinks, *"Man, this is one lazy question."*

Comment: @Ike u got me. I do feel the same..:)

Comment: I thought the purpose of Stack Overflow was to provide a place to gather and share knowledge not just simple and easy knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I provide an answer where I don't know the answer? :-D

This type of question establishes a grey zone I frequently think about on SO.

If we look at the site's standards for what it encourages to be a good question, I would say the obvious path is down-vote and close -- too broad. I see one person did that already.

But what about site posterity? There is this goal, commonly-stated, which is for the site to become the uber database for questions people might be tempted to ask, a knowledge resource. An ideal cited here is to prevent questions from being asked since they've been asked and answered already.

The highest priority there should be the most common kind of questions, and the most common kind of questions might look more like this than, *"What's wrong with this MCVE which is very specific to what I'm working on that probably no one else will ever look for given the context I provided?"*

I realize this shouldn't be ambiguous, that I shouldn't be questioning this so much. I'm not supposed to be hesitating so much here, I'm supposed to down-vote and close this obviously lazy and broad question. The question is clearly poor by the standards the site encourages. But it's potentially good if not great by the goals the site wants to achieve provided it's not a dupe. It's FAQ-worthy.

So I don't know, I'm conflicted here. I might even place a bounty on such a question. I realize I'm being far from exemplary, that such actions are far from what's encouraged of an SO user by doing such a thing, but I don't think such an action is actually misaligned with the site's ultimate goals. This is the ultimate source of confusion and conflict for me. I don't know. There's the standards on one hand and the goals on the other, and I've never been very good at keeping my mouth shut when I feel like the standards and goals are misaligned in some way.

Comment: I think this question is documentation-worthy, not high-quality Q&A-worthy. It should be documented on MongoDB's web site. If it's not, perhaps it's better geared toward the upcoming Documentation site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think the difficulty I'm having is documentation vs. Q&A-worthy. I'm judging at least in part by what the site historically encouraged as having the most up-votes and taking into account these cited goals. The way I'm looking at it is like, "Is this question likely to be asked (or at least wondered about) in a different form another day by someone else?"

Comment: Yeah, I think the emphasis for me is on high quality. That particular question was just a "research for me" question. I'd expect a lot more information about why the MongoDB site didn't answer the OP's question, There are other near-duplicates on SO already, asking about escaping special characters. The OP could have found those and listed the characters mentioned there as a start for the list. Also, one shouldn't go too far back in the history of SO for support on "historically encouraged", as that has changed a lot in the last few years.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think I also look at it just based on the contrast between existing questions. There's a lot like, *"What's wrong with my Newtonian physics particle simulator? Here's an MCVE."* Answer: *"you're returning a pointer to memory which is freed."* Those kinds of questions seem so useless in comparison because the question is not worded like, *"How do pointers/stack memory work?"* when that's the gist of it. Instead it's worded and put into a context like, *"What's wrong with my Newtonian physics particle simulator?"*

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In the tags I look at a lot, it feels like more than half the questions fit in this kind of troubleshooting category, and from a knowledge base perspective, they're worse than useless. It's like now if someone does a search on Newtonian physics or particle simulation, they end up finding a question which basically boils down to a most basic misunderstanding of how pointers work in C, nothing to do with particles. So these kinds of general questions start to look like gemstones next to all these troubleshooter questions which often only contribute misleading info to the site.